# NetSuite - updating external Id issue

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I tried updating the external Id on a customer record as I had set that value with the incorrect ID. However, upon an import it fails with the error message - This entity already exists.

Are we not able to update external IDs?

Comment: How did you update external Ids?

Comment: Yes, you can update external IDs through import. Let us know how did you do this, so we can helps identify the mistake.

Comment: I must have done something incorrect as I just did it again and it worked. I simply imported the internal and updated the external  ID. All good, thanks chaps.

Answer (score 3):

You can update the external Ids via import update.  Export the list with internal and external Ids then re-import with update.

Or you can just change your external Ids on your import.  Lot of times the external Id is arbitrary (unless its not.  i.e. it is the Id of an external source)